# Binding DisplayMemberBinding of a GridViewColumn to an element in a list

Tags: wpf

How do you DisplayMemberBinding of a GridViewColumn to an element in a list?

Item Class:

```
public class duration
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<DateTime> TimingList {get; set;}
}
```

I have 2 GridViewColumn:

- The 1st one is to binded to TimingList[0] element.
- The 2nd one is binded to TimingList[(TimingList.Count - 1)] or last element in the list. However the number of item in the list is dynamically changing.

How can I do this in Xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `List<DateTime> TimingList {get; set;}` Observable i.e

```
ObservableCollection<DateTime> TimingList {get; set;}
```